# Optimal Transport Map for Gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, optimal-transport

In the book "Computational Optimal Transport", the authors claim that the optimal transport map between two Multivariate Gaussian distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ is given by:
$$
T: x \mapsto m_\nu + A(x-m_\mu),
$$
where
$$
A = \Sigma_\mu^{-1/2} (
\Sigma_\mu^{1/2}
\Sigma_\nu
\Sigma_\mu^{1/2})^{1/2}
\Sigma_\mu^{-1/2}= A^T
$$

Now, I'm trying to calculate this matrix $A$ using a computer, and I was wondering if there is some Linear Algebra technique to do this computation efficiently. Does this matrix $A$ represents something known, like a decomposition or something?

Comment: How does $A$ so defined differ from $\Sigma_\nu$?

Comment: My bad, had a typo.

Comment: You can have a look at the [original proof](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379582901124). The quantity is related to [Schur complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) which occur among other things in the [Conditional distribution of Multivariate Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions), the [Matrix Inversion Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), [Block Matrix Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion), etc.